# Need a macro to validate the the template

Tags: macros

I have a template contains a list of headings (`B1` to `B25`) and the corresponding related data. I need a macro such that if I run this macro, It should show the mistake in the header cell number

For example, take a student record having these column headings:
(sheet name=`Student`)

```
Sno, name, class, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6, total, grade,...etc.
```

If I run a macro with an error in `B3` value `="Cass"` then it should show the error message as "`Error in B3`".

Comment: welcome Maruthi, could you precise what language you are talking about, seems you talk about excel vba but not sure

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Show what you have tried, the relevant code and the specific issues you are having. You may find http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help useful. Edit the question to add details. If it cannot be salvaged then consider deleting this question. As it stands now it can only gather downvotes which impacts your ability to ask questions. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked

Comment: I think you are asking in `excel-vba` language, If yes please add its tag and don't use `macros` tag because it's not for office or excel macro, And also add some codes have you tried ;).